# How to hide the year in archive link

Tags: archives, date

I am using the following code to show the archive link by month.

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit='.date('m').'&show_post_count=1'); ?>
```

but it shows as

- december 2013 (3)
- november 2013 (2)

but i need to just months only as..

- december (3)
- november (2)

how can I do that in some easy steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regexp to remove the year, though it's a little hacky:

```
$string = wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=20&echo=0');
$pattern = ' ((19|20)\d{2}(</a>))';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '\\3', $string);
```

Answer from this stackoverflow question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759720/have-wp-get-archives-return-a-string-with-no-year-in-it

Comment: it's working very fine. but I dont understand the code. could you please explian it?

Comment: What this code does is it returns your archive list as a plain html string, and then uses a regular expression (like find and replace) to remove any occurrences of 'date' from it.

' (19|20)\d{2}' means look for a space followed by either 12 or 20, and select it + the next two digits

after removing the dates in brackets it echoes the list to the DOM

You can experiment with regular expressions here:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/